# How to install packages from list with zypper?

Tags: opensuse, autoyast, zypper

**End state.** I want to reformat my / partition, reinstall opensuse tumbleweed, and have the same packages installed then as now.

**Problem.** I made what appears to be a poor choice, formatting the root filesystem as btrfs. The 20 GB I had for it was plenty previously with, say, ext3, but I can't keep up with the snapshot management with snapper with the large number of updates tumbleweed does.

**Partial success.** I can export my repository list with `sudo zypper lr -u --export repo.list`, and add that back to a fresh install with `sudo zypper addrepo repo.list`. I can export a list of installed pakcages with `sudo zypper search --installed-only > installed.packages` or `rpm -qa | sort`.

But I don't know how to install packages from a list, or generate a list of packages that can be used by opensuse at distribution install time.

Edit: [autoyast](https://doc.opensuse.org/projects/autoyast/) may be the way to go, but is more heavyweight than I was looking for.

Comment: the problem is that - once installed - you don't have the rpm files anymore; they reside on some online repositories or even on the install disk; so there is no guarantee that - given the list - you can reinstall each of those rpms...

Comment: Sure, I'm not too concerned about the particular version, I'd just like a starting point to get close to the packages that I tend to install after a fresh OS install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `--queryformat` to list package names without version

```
rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}\n" > installed_pkgs.txt
```

To install, pipe content of the file to `xargs`

```
cat installed_pkgs.txt | xargs sudo zypper install
```

Comment: There's a UUOC there.

Answer (score 1):

It might be slow, but you can use this bash script:

```
IFS=$'\n'

for package in `cat installed.packages`; do
    zypper install $package
done
```

Comment: I think the issue with that is the number of packages dependent on other packages (kde, python modules ...), and the ones that require license acceptance or other user interaction.

Comment: Doesn't zypper handle dependencies? And you can still interact with it. I see no reason why it won't work, even if it's not optimal.

Comment: you are correct; I thought about that as I was mowing the lawn. There are flags like `--auto-agree-with-licenses` and `--no-confirm` (to say "yes" automatically). What I was thinking of is there should be a way if you're installing 500 servers to all be the same, to pass in a list of repos and packages either at install or just post-install.

Comment: @A.R.Diederich Cool. Well, if nobody comes up with something better, you have you're option. Good luck!

Comment: I'm doing this for a simple desktop change. I found that I also needed to strip the version number and the architecture off the package name. I did it with "package_noarch=${package%.*}" and "package_name=${package_noarch%-*-*}" and it seems to work because the openSUSE version numbers are "package-version-build.arch". (I may have needed to strip versions because I'm on Tumbleweed, so version number change - this may not be necessary for other people).

Answer (score 0):

I have had good results using an exported list (from `rpm -qa | cut ...`) as a way to snapshot a particular configuration and then replicated it using:

```
# cat packages.txt | xargs -I {} zypper -n in -l {}
```

but you need to be sure there are no extra spaces in the list of packages.

I *think* that a more robust solution might be:

```
# xargs -a packages.txt -I {} sudo zypper -n in -l {}
```

as I think it won't have problems w/ stray spaces, but haven't tested it (yet).

Be sure to use `sudo` if you don't use `su`!

I didn't see the other solutions mention the **-I {}** ... **{}** requirement for this work w/o balking.

The only problem is getting the automatic import and acceptance of GPG keys from my imported list of repos (step 1, before install/update the software is to be sure the repo with the software is actually available...)  Not sure why it isn't working as advertised.